# What does _, do in Python

Tags: python, opencv

Can somebody explain me the function of _, in Python? I found this in the following codesnipped.

```
@property
def frame(self):
    if self._enteredFrame and self._frame is None:
        _, self._frame = self._capture.retrieve (channel = self.channel)
        return self._frame
```

I never saw this before.

Comment: It's a variable that automatically gets assigned the result of each expression executed by the shell.

Comment: see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` is just a variable like any other, however there are a few (contradictory) conventions for a variable called `_`. The one you see here is when you need to assign a result to a value that is not subsequently used: the `retrieve` method is returning two values and the programmer is only interested in the second one.

`_` is also used in the interactive shell to store the result of the last expression.

`_` is also used in some code as the name of a function that will translate a string, so `_("some string")` will lookup the string in a language specific table and return the appropriate translation or the original string if no translation is available.

Answer (score 1):

`_` is a variable name.

`self._capture.retrieve` returns a seqeunce with 2-elements, and the following statement assign the first element to `_`, and the second element to `self._frame`. (tuple unpacking)

```
_, self._frame = self._capture.retrieve(channel=self.channel)
```

Conventionally, `_` is used to ignore the value.

Comment: I understand that _, is not one thing, but _ and , So maybe better writen like _ ; self._frame = ....

Comment: @mharms, If you replace `,` with `;`, it become different thing.  Think about this: `a, b = 1, 2` and `a; b = 1, 2`. The second will cause an error if `a` was not assigned before; and the value of `b` will be different.

Comment: Sorry the ; was a typeerror, I meant a space between the underscore and the colon(,).      _ , self._frame = .... Now its clear for me, thank you!

Comment: @mharms, Don't put a space before `,`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id19